# Problems with JQuery gettings ID's to a php table with a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table that is created since a select from the table. 
This is my table, including php and html sentences.

```
  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> ID </th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Consulta</th>
                        <th>Carnet Estudiantil</th>
                        <th>Escuela</th>
                        <th> Eliminar </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                  <?php  
                  session_start();

                        foreach ($_SESSION['rows'] as $key=> $row) {
                 ?>
                        <tr>
                           <td><?php echo $row->id; $id = $row->id ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->nombre ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->email ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->consulta ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->carnet_estudiantil ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->escuela ?></td>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->id?>" name="eliminar" id="id_eliminar" hidden>
                            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Eliminar" id="eliminar"></td>             
                        </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                ?>
                  </tbody>
```

and it works correctly. But problems is when I try to get these values from id_eliminar or eliminar in a jquery(ajax) function.

```
 $('#eliminar').click(function(){
               var dato=$('#eliminar').val(); 
               var dato1=$('#id_eliminar').val();
               console.log(dato);
               console.log(dato1);
                $.ajax({
                   method:"POST",
                   type: "POST",
                    url:'../Models/AlumnosClass.php',
                    data:{dato:dato,dato1:dato1},
                    beforeSend:function(){
                            Swal.fire({
                            type: 'warning',
                            title: 'Alerta',
                            text: '¿Seguro que deseas eliminar este usuario?',
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: 'Si',
                            cancelButtonText: 'No cancel!',
                            reverseButtons: true
                        })
                    },
                    success:function(response)
                    {

                    }

              }); 
            });
```

This code is only taking the first ID to the table, first register, first user, but is not taking the others registers.
What should do I?

Comment: IDs must be unique, you should use classes for `#eliminar` and `#id_elimnar` instead.

Comment: i tried this one, but still doesnt work : (. It only takes values from first register.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary eliminar" value="Eliminar" data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"></td>

$(".eliminar").on('click', function() {
   var ID = $(this).data('id');

   console.log("The ID you clicked is: " + ID);
});
```

I've created a quick JSFiddle here as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/1wLsfnmt/1/

**Example**

```
<table>
  <td>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary eliminar" value="Click" data-id="1">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary eliminar" value="Click" data-id="2">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary eliminar" value="Click" data-id="3">
  </td>
</table>

$(".eliminar").on('click', function() {
   var ID = $(this).data('id');

   alert("The ID you clicked is: " + ID);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Richards! This is so helpful. Can I use same function to get name too? data-name in name camp to the table?